# algorithm used in nlm function in R

Tags: r, optimization

What is the exact algorithm used in nlm function in R. The documentation says:

> Description
>
> This function carries out a minimization of the function f using a
>   Newton-type algorithm. See the references for details.

Then in references:

> References
>
> Dennis, J. E. and Schnabel, R. B. (1983) Numerical Methods for
>   Unconstrained Optimization and Nonlinear Equations. Prentice-Hall,
>   Englewood Cliffs, NJ.
>
> Schnabel, R. B., Koontz, J. E. and Weiss, B. E. (1985) A modular
>   system of algorithms for unconstrained minimization. ACM Trans. Math.
>   Software, 11, 419–440.

Out of these references, first one is a book and I do not know where to look at in the book. Second is a 42 page paper which describes a system of algorithms as implemented in FORTRAN package `UNCMIN`. I did not read it, but then I am not sure if reading it completely will give answer to my question. (given that I don't know anything about FORTRAN it seems harder to start with).

Then as per the documentation

> Source
>
> The current code is by Saikat DebRoy and the R Core team, using a C
>   translation of Fortran code by Richard H. Jones.

So `nlm` is translated, and not directly built using algorithm. So is there any algorithm/pseudo code for the Fortran code by  Richard H.

Comment: The Newton-Type method in nlm estimates the gradient numerically then applies Newton Raphson.

Comment: The Newton-Type method in nlm estimates the gradient numerically then applies Newton Raphson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Source Code

You can [find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365843/source-code-of-nlm-function-in-stats-package) the source code in

- a wrapper function `nlm`:  r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/src/optimize.c
- the function `optif9` (another wrapper) and `optdrv` performing the algorithm: r-source/src/appl/uncmin.c

#### Three algorithms and relation with the Dennis and Schnabel reference

The algorithm seems to contain three methods:

- **line search** See section 6.3 Line searches
- **double dogleg** See section 6.4.2 The double dogleg step
- **more-hebdon** See section 6.4.1 Hookstep.

  I guess that 'more-hebdon' refers to Moré J.J. (1977) [Levenberg--Marquardt
  algorithm: implementation and theory](https://www.osti.gov/biblio/7256021) and Hebden M.D. (1973) [An
  algorithm for minimization using exact second derivatives](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.716.2997)

Note that this is much like the description of the FORTRAN code:

> The novel feature of UNCMIN is that it is a modular system of algorithms, containing three different step selection strategies (line search, dogleg, and optimal step) that may be combined with either analytic or finite difference gradient evaluation, and either analytic, finite difference or BFGS Hessian approximation.

#### NLM uses line-search

In the source code of the `nlm` function in the optimize.c file you can see that the first method is chosen explicitly

```
method = 1; /* Line Search */
```

Line search is an alternative method to the Newton's method (or the Newton–Raphson method), to find an optimal step to find the root of a function (or stationary point when performed on the derivative of a function). With Newton's method you would compute the stepsize analytically using the reciprocal/inverse of the slope/gradient. With the line search method you use some iterative algorithm to find an optimal stepsize.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the exact sections and the source code.